# shiny app works locally, but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

i have created this app with sql server connection and its worked correctly on my device but after publishing it i get this error **The application failed to start** and this is what i get in this error page:

```
    Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    serverInfo


Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


Attaching package: ‘RODBCext’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:RODBC’:

    odbcFetchRows, sqlFetchMore


Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=************;database=*******;uid=****;pwd=*****") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
Warning in odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=************\\.,1435;database=************;uid=****;pwd=****") :
  ODBC connection failed
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

my code will be here:
[my app code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629356/operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors-error-with-imported-data-from-sql-to-shin)

Comment: as the error says, your `ODBC` isnt configured on linux box where the app is deployed

Comment: I'm working on windows not linux

Comment: Shinyapps.io are on linix box

Comment: how can i solve that ?

Comment: When you configured the `ODBC` connection you probably specified that within the windows machine, not R. I suggest you use another package such as `RMySQL` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html

Comment: @PorkChop and i can use it to connect to SQL Server also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160485/discussion-between-pork-chop-and-believer).

Comment: @PorkChop thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using **dbConnect & DBI** libraries instead of `RODBC` and using `RSQLServer::SQLServer()` to open the connection on the sql server. and i thanks @PorkChop for give me a help in that.

Comment: Please accept this answer for others to reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer